# Why I can't use $cond to add a new field to a MongoDB collection? error multi update is not supported for replacement-style update

Tags: javascript, json, database, mongodb

I'm geting familiar with more MongoDB commands and I'm now getting an error and I don't know how I should avoid it.
My collection has many users. I'm trying to update all the users adding a new field which should be true if a person is registered in a date greater than 2020.05.05, false otherwise.
The code:

```
db.users.updateMany({},
{
  $set: {
    "fidelity": {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $gte: [
            "$registration",
            newDate("2020-05-05")
          ],
          then: true,
          else: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The error I get:
[image]

Comment: Reduce the document you are inserting, are all of the fields needed?

Comment: For the sake of the example lets consider I only have name and registration, still does not work

Comment: You should 1) verify that, 2) update the question.

Comment: Checked, I updated and now is simpler to follow

Answer (score 0):

$cond is an aggregation pipeline operator, but you are using a simple update. As a result $cond is not recognized as an operator but as a simple nested key, i.e. you are trying to write

```
{$cond: {
        if: {
          $gte: [
            "$registration",
            newDate("2020-05-05")
          ],
          then: true,
          else: false
        }
      }}
```

as the value of fidelity field. You are then told you can't have a field name starting with $ which is a MongoDB limitation.

- If you want to use the aggregation pipeline in the update, the pipeline must be provided as an array. Refer to documentation for the correct syntax.
- Otherwise remove $cond and you need to figure out a  different way of phrasing what you want.